# Getting minimum SDK and target device

Tags: android

How come starting a new project on android studio 2.2.3 doesn't let you choose minimum sdk or target devices anymore? It used to and now when you hit create new project after naming it it takes you directly to the project.

Comment: I also noticed on the Quick start screen it now says Create a new project instead of Start a new project.. Anyone else notice this or have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even after it has taken you to the project, you can change it from the build.gradle file.

There are two build.gradle files. One at the app level and another at the project level.

Open the app level build.gradle and you'll be able to see **targetSDK** and **minimumSDK** options. You can alter them there.